# Удаление текста после указаного символа

Tags: excel, visual-basic, макросы, таблицы, макрос

Пишу макрос на *VBA* для таблицы *Excel*. Смысл цикла: удалить все что стоит после ;

```
S - содержимое ячейки вида "Алексей Алеексеев;что-точто-точто-точто-то"
S1 = S
k = Len(S) - длинна строки S
For j = 1 To k 
   S1 = Left(S, j) 
   S1 = Right(S1, 1) -по итогу S1 это j-ый символ в строке 
   If S1 = ";" Then - если встречаем ; 
      S = Left(S, j - 1) - обрезаем строку
      тут хотела вставить брейкпоинт, тк дальше работа со строкой не нужна
   End If
Next j
```

Comment: Можно использовать ключевое слово Stop, для разрыва кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*VBA*. Удаление фрагментов текстов диапазона после указанного разделителя (включительно)

```
Sub DelText()
Dim rRng As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Set rRng = Range("A2:A50")

    For i = 1 To rRng.Rows.Count
        j = InStr(rRng(i).Value & ";", ";")
        rRng(i).Value = Left$(rRng(i).Value, j - 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

То же самое (для одной ячейки) функцией пользователя (*UDF*)

```
Function fDelText(r As Range, Optional sSep As String = ";") As String
    fDelText = Left$(r.Value, InStr(r.Value & sSep, sSep) - 1)
End Function
```

В ячейку - формула с созданной функцией:

```
=fDelText(A2)
```

Если нужно, с указанием другого разделителя:

```
=fDelText(A2;"x")
```